# Determining the maximum likelihood.

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,...X_n$ be a sample from a distribution with probability density

$$p_{\theta} (x) = \theta (1+x)^{-(1+\theta)}, \text{ for } x \geq 0$$

and $0$ elsewhere , with $\theta >0 $ unknown. Determine the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$

---

After calculations, I lead to

$$\theta = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} log(1+x_i)}$$

Is there a way to simplify this more?

Comment: And finally, the result is already a simple formula.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a typo when solving the mse. Thanks